# What kind of time is measured in the default Rails logging in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When the Rails logs says something like

```
Completed 200 OK in 454.8ms (Views: 117.9ms | ActiveRecord: 199.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

What kind of time is being displayed? CPU time, wall time, or something else?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/performance_testing.html#request-logging mentions that time is measured, but not what kind of time. I haven't found any other documentation in the Rails Guides about logging, apart from how to generate messages in the Rails logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wall-time.

Check the implementation of the Notification Instrumentation:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2746a227fbb7e56bd51ab47fa97919f206972ab2/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb

and the implementation of the LogSubscriber:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5eb2423b6e431ba53e3836d58449e7e810096b4/actionpack/lib/action_controller/log_subscriber.rb

and this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activesupport/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb

it is using `Time.now`, which is wall-time.